# Druid: how it uses cache and OS page cache?

Tags: bigdata, druid

I'm observing that Druid query performance can benefit from the previous queries. Thus, I'm trying to understand the reasons.
I Know that Druid uses cache (I'm using cache in the Broker), but this cache just stores the result of the queries per segment (right?). However, I have noticed that if the subsequent queries use the same segments, the performance improves.

Example:

1. Select sum(metric), dimteste2, dimteste3 from table x where dimteste='x' group by dimteste2, dimteste3 -> **2 seconds**
2. Select sum(metric), dimteste2, dimteste3 from table x where dimteste3='y' group by dimteste2, dimteste3 -> **0.5 seconds**

I searched and found that this behavior can be achieved by the OS page cache. Based on my research, I think that Druid, during the first query to the datasource, loads the necessary segments to memory (OS page cache). And the segments can be read faster in the next queries.

Am I right?
I looked in the Druid documentation and I was unable to find anything helpful.

Can you please give me some help explaining this awesome behavior?

Best regards,

José Correia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Druid does uses caching to improve the performance at various levels. At segment level on historicals and druid query level on broker. The more memory you give it the faster it works.

Below is the documentation on the caching -

**Query Caching**

Druid supports query result caching through an LRU cache. Results are stored on a per segment basis, along with the parameters of a given query. This allows Druid to return final results based partially on segment results in the cache and partially on segment results from scanning historical/real-time segments.

Segment results can be stored in a local heap cache or in an external distributed key/value store. Segment query caches can be enabled at either the Historical and Broker level (it is not recommended to enable caching on both).

**Query caching on Brokers**

Enabling caching on the broker can yield faster results than if query caches were enabled on Historicals for small clusters. This is the recommended setup for smaller production clusters (< 20 servers). Take note that when caching is enabled on the Broker, results from Historicals are returned on a per segment basis, and Historicals will not be able to do any local result merging.

**Query caching on Historicals**

Larger production clusters should enable caching only on the Historicals to avoid having to use Brokers to merge all query results. Enabling caching on the Historicals instead of the Brokers enables the Historicals to do their own local result merging and puts less strain on the Brokers.

> Druid broker doesn't do anything directly at the OS page cache, if
>   there is virtual memory available by the os, than based on memory
>   requirements the heaps are allocated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply mdeora. I saw the documentation, but I still don't fully understand.
How can I explain that a more complex query, executed after a simpler one to the same datasource take drastically less time to return results?
I disabled the Druid cache and the behavior is the same. Thus, this is due to OS page cache, right?

Comment: @JoséCorreia the query results are stored in an LRU cache at segment level along with query params, so if you again make the query with same results than hypothetically no lookups are done, only single key-value lookup is done at segment level.

Comment: I'm talking about similar queries, but with different results. I tested this using two similar queries, but the second one uses attributes with larger cardinality. Teorically, the second query should take more time than the query 1.
Important note: I disabled Druid cache to test this. So, there is no LRU cache. I set "useCache" and "populateCache" to false (http://druid.io/docs/latest/querying/query-context.html).

Comment: As far as caching is concerned -  its purely based on the memory heap available to druid for putting the segments data in druid. Also please note there many other factors which can affect the query time, eg. number of segments used, query type (topn, select, group by etc..).  I can't think of any specific role of OS page cache in this case.

Comment: Please see rohit kochar's answer in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41415296/druid-how-to-cache-all-historical-node-data-in-memory and let me know your opinion.

Comment: The mention of OS page cache there is in context to loading the segments in the system memory (RAM), through JVM heap. Once the segment is in memory, the queries to it would be faster since no disk access. Now this is subject to the segment size and system RAM size. I think i understood it wrong when you wrote OS Page cache, thought it as server VM. (Treating some disk space as RAM since actual RAM is less)

Comment: Exactly. So, Druid just loads the segments into memory the first time I do a query right? Before that, Druid has to consult local disk (on historical nodes) and load the necessary segments to answer this query into memory (RAM), through JVM heap. The next queries can benefit if they use some of the segments, previously loaded into memory.

Is this the correct explanation?